# How to set file name to a added and not removed treeview node

Tags: c#, treeview, tex

At the beginning, I add my parent and child nodes to a tree view, with button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            treeView1.Nodes.Add("chapter1"); 
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("chapter2"); 
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("chapter3");

        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("sec1");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("sec2");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("sec3");

        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("sec1");
        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("sec2");
        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("sec3");

        treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("sec1");
        treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("sec2");
        treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add("sec3");
}
```

Later I create a remove button click event:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveChecked(treeView1.Nodes);
        }

        void RemoveChecked(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in FindCheckedNodes(nodes))
            {
                nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
            }
        }


        private List<TreeNode> FindCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    checkedNodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    // find checked childs        
                    checkedNodes.AddRange(FindCheckedNodes(node.Nodes));
                }
            }
            return checkedNodes;

}
```

Now, I want to generate everything what is added and not removed to a file. I am working with latex files, so I need to write just \include . So I use header and footer files and between them final - where I should get both together and add my generated options. So I am thinking of 3 button click event, for example:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var header = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\header.tex");
            var footer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\footer.tex");
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(header);
            // if node added and not removed with chapter1 text , sb.Appendline("\include {chapter1})

            sb.AppendLine(footer);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C: \dir\final.tex", sb.ToString());
        }
```

Maybe you can offer me how to make work my part which is commented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeNode has a Tag property which you can use to pin any object to it, so, pinned is the path, which is later used to write the final block.

Also refactored the tree view node appending part.

This should work:

```
private TreeNode Append(TreeNode parent, string text)
{
    TreeNode newNode;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        newNode = parent.Nodes.Add(text);
        newNode.Tag = parent.Tag + "\\{" + text + "}";
    }
    else
    {
        newNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(text);
        newNode.Tag = "{" + text + "}";
    }
    return newNode;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode chapter1 = Append(null, "chapter1");
    Append(chapter1, "sec1");
    Append(chapter1, "sec2");
    Append(chapter1, "sec3");

    TreeNode chapter2 = Append(null, "chapter2");
    Append(chapter2, "sec1");
    Append(chapter2, "sec2");
    Append(chapter2, "sec3");

    TreeNode chapter3 = Append(null, "chapter3");
    Append(chapter3, "sec1");
    Append(chapter3, "sec2");
    Append(chapter3, "sec3");
}

private void IncludeChapterAndSections(TreeNode treeNode, StringBuilder sb)
{
    TreeNodeCollection children = treeNode != null ? treeNode.Nodes : treeView1.Nodes;
    if (treeNode != null)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("\\include {0}", treeNode.Tag.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    foreach (TreeNode child in children)
    {
        IncludeChapterAndSections(child, sb);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var header = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\header.tex");
    var footer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\footer.tex");
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(header);
    IncludeChapterAndSections(null, sb);
    sb.AppendLine(footer);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\dir\final.tex", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: So you offer totally change my adding event process?   And can you comment how `"\\ include {0}` part works? Also, maybe I missed to say i need good UI in this project.

Comment: It is up to you. If you don't change it, you can still add the tags as you wish, or while recursively writing the final block, you can use the Text property of TreeNode instead of tag, but then you should also build the paths, which I am doing while adding the tree nodes to the tree

Comment: I am not sure for the sections if \include {chapter1}\{sec1} is ok by the way. Is it?

Comment: No I want to everything separated, First I will build main latex file, where will be only chapter. So I need to write \inlcude chapter1, \inlcude chapter2, etc. If I use my code everything looks clear and simple, I just need some how find that treeview1.Node[0] isn't removed from added list and write to file \include {chapter1}.

Comment: But when you recursively iterate the nodes of the tree view, only the nodes which are not removed will be there?

Comment: I mean in button click 3

Comment: Yes, In winforms window I am generating a list of added and not removed list. So on my opinion I need somehow from button click 3 , check if node not removed and if it is not then write to final block include.

Comment: What Iam saying is, you already removed those nodes from the tree. According to your code, the removed nodes do not exist in the tree view.

Comment: Yes, It is shown and everything works. But I need one more button event, because I want to use appendLine somehow. I  can write appendLine when I am  adding  elements, but they are not being removed from my file after removing option.

Comment: Your code is overwriting the file with each click of button 3. You did not mention anything like this (real-time update of the output file) when a node is removedor added. Isthat what you need?

Comment: No, I need overwrite my file each time. My project is a manual. Sometimes I don't one or two chapter/sections of manual. So I am making this program. So i need somehow write that includes in main latex file. And nothing happens for me, I have tried looking for treeview1.Node[0].text and check it, but I failed.

Comment: Then, I can only help if you provide the full source code (I don't think it is exactly as you posted here)